# Is a simple suggestion to do something apparently unrelated, with no explanation, a high quality answer?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, answer-quality

I was reviewing the first posts queue and [a very short answer came up as an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163809/):

> Just added two factor authentication to Apple ID and It worked. Don't know how it's related but it worked for me. Do the same. Cheers!

I failed the test. I down voted because it seemed short, and the author didn't explain why this worked.

So here are my remarks:

- How is this a high quality answer?
- Are answers considered high quality only because they have a high score?

Comment: It apparently was helpful to 11 people.

Comment: Short does not imply low quality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters true the answer is correct but being high quality should be different something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1342402
is high quality

Comment: @maazza: the First Post queue is not asking you to rate anything less than that the highest-voted answer on the site as low quality however. Length is not an indicator of quality either. That post is not the greatest example, and I wouldn't worry too much about it, but it solved a problem and other people found it helpful too.

Comment: @Stijn true but between low quality and high quality  there should be some middle ground

Comment: I don't even see a point of discussion. This helped a lot of people. I've seen like 1k hits on the day I answered this and apparently this solves the issue completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a "high quality" answer. The length is not the problem *per se*; it is the fact that it contains no rationale and no explanation of how to do what it proposes.

It barely meets the minimum bar for "an answer". As such, although it would be inappropriate to flag it for deletion, it *is* badly in need of editing. Downvoting would also be a reasonable choice. Attempting to do either of these would have caused you to fail the audit, which is unexpected and wrong.

It was selected as an audit because 11 people found the answer helpful, but that is not always the best metric. Sometimes, things get upvoted that aren't exactly gems. These upvotes all came in shortly after the answer was posted, within a 48-hour period. It has not had any upvotes after that initial flurry of activity, suggesting that this answer is *not* one of those that is enduringly useful to Google traffic. (In fact, it looks like the entire question is about a highly-localized case of service disruption, and its continued presence serves little to no value whatsoever. The question is equally as low-quality as its top answer.)

Note that you are not the first person to fail an audit centered around this answer. [Hamza Zafeer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14703557) and [ρяσѕρєя K](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14719229) were also tripped up here.

When you fail an obviously incorrect audit, you should return to the post and do what you would normally have done in the review queue, including editing and/or voting.